# cannot change orientation automatically

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a TabBarController which two UIViewControllers inside ,In order to camptible to landscape ,I add following code in the first ViewController:

```
 - (BOOL) shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{    return YES; }

- (void)willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration
{
if (toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait || toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown) {
      //handle with portait
}else{
      //handle with landscape
   }
}
```

and Actually it works,but I encountered a problem :when I change orientation in the second ViewController and return the first ViewController , it cannot change orientation automatically, I need to change the orientation manually,So I want to a solution to avoid this

Answer (score 1):

```
[[UIDevice currentDevice] performSelector:NSSelectorFromString(@"setOrientation:") withObject:(id)UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarOrientation:UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft animated:true];
```

This will do. And don't forget to change the frames of your views after this method call, example:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [[UIDevice currentDevice] performSelector:NSSelectorFromString(@"setOrientation:") withObject:(id)UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarOrientation:UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft animated:true];

    // Screen is turned now, change all views their frames
    [myButton setFrame:CGRectMake(480, 20, 0, 0)];
    [myLabel setFrame:CGRectMake(480, 50, 0, 30)];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You'd try to use for specify orientation You want to (f.e landscape):

```
- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations {
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscape;
}
```

Comment: not specify orientation, it's orientation change in other viewController cannot make a viewController to change orientation

Answer (score 0):

Before the code You Have to Check your Device in Project > Summary - you must Click on Portrait , Landscape. ( Supported Interface Orientation ) as per your Orientation Requirement.

- Jatin Chauhan

jatinchauhan.it@gmail.com